# clone subclass of class that :contains specific string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to clone a specific subclass of a class that contains specific text but  can't find a way to do it. **can't use :eq() or :firstchild  because there are multiple classes with  the same name and can change the order**

jquery I have been trying to select multiple classes

```
 var rate = $(".header a").text()


  if  (t_hotelCode="zzzz")
  {
    if (rate == "Super")
    {


      $('.header a:contains("Super").policy').clone().insertAfter(".policy")
      $(".childrenPolicy").eq(1).each(function(){
      $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Policy', 'other'))
});
    }
  }
```

if I  use the following it works but it clones every single class named **policy**

```
 var rate = $(".header a").text()
  if  (t_hotelCode="zzzz")
  {
    if (rate == "Super")
    {
  $('.Policy').clone().insertAfter(".Policy")
  $(".childrenPolicy").eq(1).each(function(){
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Policy', 'other'))
    });
    }
  }
```

HTML of class I  am trying to clone, I can only use string  ***h4 super h4***  everything else changes

```
<div id="roomsrates_list" class="ratelistview">
  <div id="room_1" class="roomrate room closed">
    <div class="header">
    <div class="room" style="display:none;">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="rates">
        <div id="room1_rate1" class="rate opened" relgross="" rel="" data-rrc="IC">
           <div class="ratesperday hidden">
           <div class="layerrateinfos hidden">
           <div class="header">
              <a class="iconbutton iconbutton1" href="#"> </a>
              <h4>Super</h4>
              <div class="rateicons">
              <div class="price">
              <div class="discountPrice"> </div>
              <div class="clear"> </div>
           </div>
           <div class="border"> </div>
           <div class="content" style="">
           <p></p>
           <a class="details details" href="Javascript:void(0)">
           <a class="details details_policies" href="Javascript:void(0)">
           <div class="clear"> </div>
           <div class="detailcontent_policies" style="">
             <div class="depositPolicy">
               <strong>Deposit</strong>
               <br>
               <p></p>
               <br>
            </div>
           <div class="cancellationPolicy">
           <div class="checkinDescription">
           <div class="Policy">
        </div>
        <div class="detail" style="display:none;">
        <div class="clear"> </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
<div class="clear"> </div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "subclass".  There's really no such thing when you're talking about the DOM and/or CSS.

Comment: I am trying to clone  class "policy" which is under class "content". But only clone the "policy" for the **h4** named "super"

Comment: I just need to clone "policy" so I can change the string text and add another policy, but that will only apply to the "super" policy. there are more "policy" classes but under different **h4** i.e "best rate" has another "policy" but I can't clone this one

Comment: added the rest of the HTML

Comment: Sorry took so long, an answer awaits.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might get you started:

```js
$('#mybutt').click(function(){
 var supr = $('.content>.rates h4:contains(Super)');
 /*
 var s2 = sing.closest('.layerrateinfos'); //('.layerrateinfos');
 var s3 = s2.find('.policies .Policy');
 var s4 = s3.text();
 alert( s4 );
 */
 var pols = supr.closest('.layerrateinfos').find('.policies');
 var pol = pols.find('.Policy');
 pol.clone().text('New Policy').appendTo( pols );
});
```

```css
#room1_rate1{background:wheat;}
#room1_rate2{background:pink;}
#room1_rate3{background:palegreen;}
#room1_rate4{background:beige;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
 <div class="rates">
  <div id="room1_rate1" class="rate opened" data-rrc="CK">
   <div class="ratesperday hidden">
    <div class="layerrateinfos hidden">
     <div class="header">
      <a class="iconbutton iconbutton1" href="#"> </a>
      <h4>Single</h4>
      <div class="clear"> </div>
     </div>
     <div class="border"> </div>
     <div class="clear"> </div>
     <div class="policies" style="">
      <div class="Policy">Policy Div</div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="room1_rate2" class="rate opened" data-rrc="CK">
   <div class="ratesperday hidden">
    <div class="layerrateinfos hidden">
     <div class="header">
      <a class="iconbutton iconbutton1" href="#"> </a>
      <h4>Super</h4>
      <div class="clear"> </div>
     </div>
     <div class="border"> </div>
     <div class="clear"> </div>
     <div class="policies" style="">
      <div class="Policy">Policy Div</div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="room1_rate3" class="rate opened" data-rrc="CK">
   <div class="ratesperday hidden">
    <div class="layerrateinfos hidden">
     <div class="header">
      <a class="iconbutton iconbutton1" href="#"> </a>
      <h4>Double</h4>
      <div class="clear"> </div>
     </div>
     <div class="border"> </div>
     <div class="clear"> </div>
     <div class="policies" style="">
      <div class="Policy">Policy Div</div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="room1_rate4" class="rate opened" data-rrc="CK">
   <div class="ratesperday hidden">
    <div class="layerrateinfos hidden">
     <div class="header">
      <a class="iconbutton iconbutton1" href="#"> </a>
      <h4>Presidential</h4>
      <div class="clear"> </div>
     </div>
     <div class="border"> </div>
     <div class="clear"> </div>
     <div class="policies" style="">
      <div class="Policy">Policy Div</div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
 </div>
</div>
<button id="mybutt">Clone Summat</button>
```

[Here is a jsFiddle of the same](https://jsfiddle.net/4qfbkrbe/) to experiment with *(easier than playing with stack snippets)*

*You were updating question code (thank you) while I was composing answer, so if anything not clear leave a comment.*

---

Notes:

1. Use of `contains:` in `$('.content>.rates h4:contains(Super)')` [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_contains.asp) *Note that the `>` might not be necessary - a space might be preferable.*
2. In the jsFiddle, I show how I built the correct jQuery selector, using several steps and `console.log` with `.length` at each step
3. Use `.text()` if only contains text, or `.html()` if need to add HTML tags also